# Find the range of year in pandas especially with hyphen formats?

Tags: regex, pandas

Given the data below, I want to print the list of team who debut their match between 1934 to 1948. Since the Debut column is object, I am not able to get the column data in integer form.

```
Team    Debut
0       Real Madrid 1929
1       Barcelona   1929
2       Atletico Madrid 1929
3       Valencia    1931-32
4       Athletic Bilbao 1929
5       Sevilla 1934-35
6       Espanyol    1929
7       Real Sociedad   1929
8       Zaragoza    1939-40
9       Real Betis  1932-33
10      Deportivo La Coruna 1941-42
11      Celta Vigo  1939-40
12      Valladolid  1948-49
```

Can somebody please help to give an idea how to achieve it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What would be the expected output, for example, does 1941-42 counts as 1941 or 1942?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, The expected output could be anyone either 41 or 42 depending on the range requested.

Comment: For example if the range ends in 1941?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If only the first year of the range counts, you could use [between](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html) after converting to a numeric value:

```
year = pd.to_numeric(df.Debut.str.split('-').str[0])
teams = df.Team[year.between(1934, 1948)]
print(teams)
```

**Output**

```
5                 Sevilla
8                Zaragoza
10    Deportivo La Coruna
11             Celta Vigo
12             Valladolid
Name: Team, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel for your help, This is good. So "year.between" is a method in pandas? not familiar with this till now :-)

Comment: @VinuPillai Glad I could help! Yes it is!

Comment: @VinuPillai Updated the answer!

Answer (score 2):

You can use str.extract to extract first part of the date and check if its in the required range

```
mask = df['Debut'].str.extract('(\d+)')[0].astype(int).between(1934,1948)
df[mask]

    Team    Debut
5   5   Sevilla 1934-35
8   8   Zaragoza 1939-40
10  10  Deportivo La Coruna 1941-42
11  11  Celta Vigo 1939-40
12  12  Valladolid 1948-49
```